# Why does $.get not load php file in another folder, error 500 instead

Tags: jquery, get

on page load, I wish to invoke a php file, so I write

...{$.get('../action.php',params, function(retcode){...} )};

which works as required, at least with Safari on a Mac.
But if I put the action.php file into a folder and write

...{$.get('../action_files/action.php',params, function(retcode){...} )};

I get a load error 500 for the php file.
I still get it if I replace the relative url by an absolute one beginning localhost:8888/
Am I falling foul of a security restriction somewhere?

Comment: Depends where `action_files` is relative to the page you are making request from. Try removing the `..` if that directory is in your root. Check server error logs for what caused the 500

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of looking at the MAMP error logs, once I found them. Deduction from what I saw there led me to realise that in a buried 'require' file there was a connection-related relative url which had to be updated as well. This has now been fixed and is now absolute. Problem solved. Thanks.